# Ansible hangs on action in handler, but works fine with action in task (reloading pf)

Tags: ansible, freebsd

I'm attempting to reload pf as part of a role to provision a FreeBSD server after copying a new pf.conf to the system.   When I do this step independently as a task as part of it's own playbook, it works flawlessly.  However, when I have exactly the same action as a handler, ansible always hangs during the execution of that handler.

The play that succeeds:

```
   - hosts: tag_Name_web ; all ec2 instances tagged with web
     gather_facts: True


   vars:
       ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python2.7
       ansible_become_pass: xxx

   tasks:

      - name: copy pf.conf
        copy:
          src: pf.template
          dest: /etc/pf.conf
        become: yes
        become_method: su

      - name: reload pf
        shell: /sbin/pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
        become: yes
        become_method: su

      - name: echo
        shell: echo "test"
        become: yes
        become_method: su
```

(I included the echo as a test, as I thought it might be succeeding because the reload was the last thing the play was doing, but it works fine).

The handler, which fails is:

```
# handlers file for jail_host
- name: Start iocage
  command: service iocage start

- name: Reload sshd
  service: name=sshd state=reloaded

- name: Reload pf
  shell: "/sbin/pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf"
```

The handler definitely gets called, and it starts to work, and then it just hangs.  (When I run pfctl -sa on the system, it shows me that the new pf.conf was actually reloaded.  So it's working, it's just never returning and therefore making the rest of the ansible run not happen).

Below is the debug output of the handler running, but I don't see any errors that I can make sense of.  There is no timeout as far as I can tell; I've let it run for 30 minutes before I Ctrl-C.

```
RUNNING HANDLER [JoergFiedler.freebsd-jail-host : Reload pf] *******************
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/commands/command.py
<54.244.77.100> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ec2-user
<54.244.77.100> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/usr/local/etc/ansible/xxx_aws.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ec2-user -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r 54.244.77.100 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487698172.0-93173364920700 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1487698172.0-93173364920700="` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487698172.0-93173364920700 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<54.244.77.100> PUT /tmp/tmpBrFVdu TO /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487698172.0-93173364920700/command.py
<54.244.77.100> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/usr/local/etc/ansible/xxx_aws.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ec2-user -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r '[54.244.77.100]'
<54.244.77.100> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ec2-user
<54.244.77.100> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/usr/local/etc/ansible/xxx_aws.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ec2-user -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r 54.244.77.100 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487698172.0-93173364920700/ /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487698172.0-93173364920700/command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<54.244.77.100> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ec2-user
<54.244.77.100> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/usr/local/etc/ansible/xxx_aws.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ec2-user -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt 54.244.77.100 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'su  root -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-cntrcxqxlwicicvwtinmaadrnzzzujfp; /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487698172.0-93173364920700/command.py; rm -rf "/home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487698172.0-93173364920700/" > /dev/null 2>&1'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"''"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
```

I've also tried a lot of other ways of reloading pf.. using the service module, using command: service pf reload, and they all have exactly the same effect.  I've also attempted to make the handler async, with

```
- name: Reload pf
  shell: "/sbin/pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf"
  async: 1
  poll: 0
```

with no change.

Does anyone have an idea as to why my role with the handler fails, while a straightforward play with tasks succeeds?  And more importantly, how can I get the handler to work properly?

Thanks in advance!

(I should note I'm using Ansible 2.2.1).

Comment: Try running Ansible with `ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1`. Then run manually the Python script generated for the handler on the target machine (then through SSH as in the trace). If it does not return to the prompt, you might then compare the script with the one for the task. If it does return, then try to modify the config and re-run, if it still ran correctly, then no clue... Can you create, and include, a full, reproducible example with Vagrant?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thanks!

That said; it doesn't seem to be doing me much good, because running it as the command (from .ansible) or the role inside the playbook after it fails the first time always succeeds. 

So... the first time it runs as a handler it fails.  Subsequent times it succeeds just fine.  The task succeeds the first time.  
Are you aware of a way to push the command to the remote server, but bail before actually running it?  That way, I could then run that command for the first time outside the playbook and see what it's doing.

Comment: Oh, also, I've never used Vagrant before, so it would be a hefty lift.  At the moment, I'm using AWS EC2 images, and I've deleted the image and run this stuff about 50 times now, and it is very repeatable there; it's never worked once on the first try.

Comment: It definitely hangs (apologies for being unclear; when I said "fails" earlier I meant "hangs") after making the change on the remote system.  As requested, I replaced "shell: /sbin/pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf" with "shell: echo 'test'" and ran the playbooks from scratch with a new EC2 instance.  I then used "python2.7 command.py explode", replaced the "echo 'test'" with "/sbin/pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf" in dubug_id/args, ran python2.7 command.py execute, and it worked and returned immediately.  So... this way seems to work perfectly.  Thank you, btw, for your help thus far.  I'm a bit out of my league.

Comment: One possibility: you are restarting `pfctl` and it might mess with the current SSH session (not really hang itself) when Ansible is running handlers. Not sure why it would affect only handlers. Asynchronous execution was a good idea, however let Ansible finish before `pfctl` is executed: `shell: "sleep 10 && /sbin/pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf"`

Comment: Thanks for all of the troubleshooting suggestions; async worked, but then another handler hung a few seconds later.  So I created another handler with "pause: seconds: 20", notified that handler when notifying the reload pf handler, and everything now works.  You  were right that the ssh session was being terminated, and ansible couldn't recover from it for some reason.

Comment: I'm in this same rut, same version of ansible, applying iptables rules with iptables-restore.  Have you noticed if this has been fixed in a future version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be more an issue with [PF](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/) not with ansible, give a try again to your playbook but this time use this on your `pf.rules`:

```
pass all
```

You can indeed also test by login to the instance and just run:

```
/sbin/pfctl -Fa -f /etc/pf.conf.all
```

where `/etc/pf.conf.all` contains `pass all`, it should not log you out or your current session should remain active.

What probably is happening is that your pf rules are dropping/flushing existing connections when applied therefore your SSH (ansible) hangs.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to techraf above, this is indeed the issue.  By making the action: "command: sleep 10; pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf" and then adding another handler to "pause: seconds: 20" before the next handler ran, it all works well now.  I'm not sure why ansible couldn't recover from the dead ssh connection, but I have a working solution now. - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the following in your handler(s)?

```
become: yes
become_method: su
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I have that in the parent role, and it's working for the other handlers (and in fact, it's working for this handler as pf actually does get the new config; if it were not getting permission escalation, it would have not gotten the config).  Also, in the debug, I see it calling su root.

Comment: Same effect; for this purpose they're identical it seems (and in fact, looking at the code of "shell.py" it's just a wrapper around "command.py" anyway, but allows more capability as far as pipes and such.  I'd started with command, but changed to shell in hopes something would change).